# Repeating Digits

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, algorithm, sequence

I have written

```
RepeatingDigits[n_Integer] :=
 Module[{id = IntegerDigits @ n, x},
  x = Differences /@ Map[Partition[id, #] &, Range[Length[id]/2]];
  If[# === {}, Return @ False, x = Length @ First @ #] &[Catenate @ Cases[x, {{0 ...} ...}]];
  If[IntegerQ[#], {Take[id, x], #}, False] &[Length[id] /x]]

RepeatingDigits /@ {1, 11, 212212, 2122126}
```

> {False, {{1}, 2}, {{2, 1, 2}, 2}, False}

I feel there should be a simpler way to find cycles in a list like  ` {1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1}.

How can I avoid to run through multiple partitions?

How can I shorten my code? `.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
f[x_] := Module[ {s = IntegerDigits@x, s1},
                s1 = s /. {y__ ..} :> {y};
                {s1, Length@s/Length@s1}]

f@212212212212
(* {{2, 1, 2}, 4}*)
```

Comment: It doesn't function for `f[12126]`. +1 anyway for `{y__ ..} :> {y}` :)

Comment: @eldo Well, I forgot you wanted a special `False` answer when the digits are non repeating. You may add a `/. {_, 1} -> False`  as ybeltukov did, but I hate functions with inhomogeneous  return types because then you need `IF[exp, trueCase, falseCase, otherCases]` to treat all special cases in the program

Comment: Interesting point. And if you would return `{}` or `{{}}` instead of `False`?

Comment: @eldo That  may be better, at least things like `Map[]` would work easier with that kind of results. However I still prefer returning `{{1,2,3,4},1}` for an input of `1234` because later I'll be able rebuild the original number using the same procedure always.

Comment: @eldo I always hate having to check whether `Solve[]` have returned a result or not when working with a recursive algorithm. See for example the odd code [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/38652/315)

Comment: @eldo I agree with belisarius, but as a side note, you can test this inhomogeneous result as `If[res === False, a, b]`, `If[TrueQ@Not@res, a, b]` or `If[res, , a, b]`.

Comment: @belisarius Señor, Please accept my acceptance - despite the terrible infix notation of this senseless comment.

Comment: @eldo Thanks! As the ex-toad told me once, the use of infix is allowed when all other options could result in expletive code, such as in `Set[año, nuevo]`

Answer (score 7):

Nice problem! Maybe something like this:

```
repeatingdigits[n_Integer] := Module[{digits = IntegerDigits[n], res = False, div}, 
  div = Divisors[Length[digits]];
  Do[With[{z = Partition[digits, d]},
    If[Equal @@ z, res = {z[[1]], Length[z]}; Break[]]], 
    {d, Reverse[Most[div]]}];
  res]

repeatingdigits /@ {1, 11, 212212, 2122126}

(* {False, {{1}, 2}, {{2, 1, 2}, 2}, False} *)
```

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to belisarius's answer

```
f[n_] := IntegerDigits@n /. l : {x__ ..} :> {{x}, Length@l/Length@{x}} /. {_, 1} -> False

f[123123]
(* {{1, 2, 3}, 2} *)

f[1]
(* False *)
```

Comment: Just perfect :)

Answer (score 3):

I have tried some String manipulation functions :

```
StringCases["342121212136" , s : (x__ ~~ (x_) ..) -> {x, s}]
```

gives the longest cycle in the string :`{{2121, 21212121}}`

If you want the shortest cycle :

```
StringCases["342121212136" , s : (Shortest@x__ ~~ (x_) ..) -> {x, s}]
```

gives : `{{21, 21212121}}`

If you are not interested in extracting cycles from within a string, you can do that that :

```
StringCases["342121212136" , s : (StartOfString ~~ x__ ~~ (x_) .. ~~ EndOfString) -> {x, s}]
```

gives : `{}`

Also `StringMatchQ` can tell you if it is exactly cyclic  :

```
StringMatchQ["342121212136" , s : (x__ ~~ (x_) ..)]
```

gives : `False`

```
StringMatchQ["21212121" , s : (x__ ~~ (x_) ..)]
```

gives :`True`

but does not give the pattern which was found.

Finally this is what I propose :

```
cycL[num_] := StringCases[ToString@num, s : (StartOfString ~~ x__ ~~ (x_) .. ~~ EndOfString) :> {x, StringLength@s/StringLength@x}];

cycL /@ {1, 11, 212212, 2122126}
```

gives : `{{}, {{1, 2}}, {{212, 2}}, {}}`
.

Comment: `cycQ` is an awesome answer! First time that I dated `StartOfString` and `EndOfString`. I hope `cycQ` will get the upvotes it deserves. +1. You should, however, remove the remaining quotation marks :)

Comment: @eldo Thanks ! The best answer was already given, i had to invent something else ;) I renamed `cycQ`, the function is not a predicate.

Answer (score 1):

To get the longest repeating subsequence and the number of its repetitions:

```
ClearAll[rDF]
rDF[a : Repeated[Longest[x__], {2, Infinity}]] := {{x}, Length[{a}]/Length[{x}]}
rDF[___] := False

rDF @@@ IntegerDigits[{1, 11, 212212, 2122126, 212212212212,  2122122122125}]
(* {False,{{1},2},{{2,1,2},2},False,{{2,1,2,2,1,2},2},False} *)
```

To get the shortest repeating subsequence and the number of its repetitions:

```
ClearAll[rDFb]
rDFb[a : Repeated[x__, {2, Infinity}]] := {{x}, Length[{a}]/Length[{x}]}
rDFb[___] := False

rDFb @@@ IntegerDigits[{1, 11, 212212, 2122126, 212212212212,  2122122122125}]
(* {False,{{1},2},{{2,1,2},2},False,{{2,1,2},4},False} *)
```

In the original post below  and in Fred's answer, change  `{d, Reverse[Most[div]]}` to `{d, Most[div]}`  to get the same output as `rDFb`.

---

**Original post:**

Using `Divisors` and a `Do` loop as in @Fred Simons's answer, but instead of `Partition`ing and checking `Equality` of all pieces,  just checking if a number is equal to itself when `RotateRight`ed by some amount:

```
ClearAll[rDF2];
rDF2[n_Integer] := Module[{str = ToString[n], res = False, sl = StringLength[ToString@n]},
   With[{div = Divisors[sl]},
    Do[If[str == StringRotateLeft[str, d],
      res = {FromDigits@StringTake[str, d], sl/d}; Break[]],
     {d, Reverse[Most[div]]}]];
   res];

rDF2 /@ {1, 11, 212212, 2122126, 212212212212, 2122122122125}
(* {False,{1,2},{212,2},False,{212212,2},False} *)
```

And a variation of Fred's `repeatingdigits`:

```
repeatingdigits2[n_Integer] := 
 Module[{digits = IntegerDigits[n], res = False, div},
  len = Length@digits; div = Divisors[Length[digits]];
  Do[If[digits == RotateLeft[digits, d], 
    res = {digits[[;; d]], len/d}; Break[]],
   {d, Reverse[Most[div]]}];
  res]

repeatingdigits2 /@ {1, 11, 212212, 2122126, 212212212212,  2122122122125}
(* {False,{1,2},{212,2},False,{212212,2},False} *)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem desirable to return `{212212,2}` rather than `{212, 4}` -- would you explain?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, good point. I assumed -- as, it seems, few others did -- the desired result was longest repeating prefix together with the number of repetitions. I conjecture the case you are suggesting can be handled by changing `Longest` to `Shortest`, or scanning the divisor list in the opposite order.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, just updated the answer covering both cases. Thanks for the good catch.